# Unable to save Authenticated User data into Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save data of authenticated users in Firebase, there are two ways to authenticate data in my app after which the user is taken to the `MainActivity.Java`. I would like to see if the user is using the application for the first time if so add the details to the user tree in Firebase RealtimeDatabase.

As of now after adding the code in OnCreate below the comment of adding the user, the app does not crash or give any errors, but it also does not hit the Firebase DB and update it.

Here is my code of the OnCreate section of the `MainActivity.Java`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Carousel

        customCarouselView = findViewById(R.id.customCarouselView);

        customCarouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);
        customCarouselView.setSlideInterval(4000);


        customCarouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);

        customCarouselView.setImageClickListener(new ImageClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                redirectToHotDeals();
            }
        });

        // -- Carousel


        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // User is signed in.
            String name = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
            String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
            String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

            NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView navUsername = headerView.findViewById(R.id.emailText);
            TextView navUID = headerView.findViewById(R.id.uid);
            navUID.setText("ID: " + uid.substring(0, 10));
            navUsername.setText(email);


        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            redirectToLogin();
        }

        // Action Bar

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Coupons List");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // Set Layout
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // Send Query to Firebase Db
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");

        // Add User to DB or Update it
        String name = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
        String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        User user = new User(name, email);
        mRef.child("User").child(fUser.getUid()).setValue(user);


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

Here is the image of the Firebase Database: I would like if the first child has the UID followed by the email and contact as its child. [image]

Here is my `User.Java`:

```
public class User {
    public String name, email, phone;

    public User(String name, String email){

    }

    public User(String name, String email, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method for signing up are you using? Email/password or phone?

Comment: Email and Google

Comment: Would you also add the root structure of the firebase database too? `User` doesn't seem to be the `Data` child.

Comment: @Mohsen I've attached the image above. DB is split into three root structures (Data, Directory and User).

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Unfortunately not. I did solve it eventually via the Firebase Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate declaration for the `NavigationView` first. Define it as follows inside your `onCreate()`:

```
navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

And then;

```
NavigationView navigationView;
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
```

---

About the Firebase data set, `User` node doesn't seem to be child of `Data` which you declared it like this:

```
mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");
mRef.child("User").child(fUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
```

Instead, try this:

```
mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("User");
mRef.child("UID").setValue(user);
```

Note that we need to be sure that `User` node is the reference in here. It seems like there is another root reference which we need to check the whole structure but I've just give you the path of how to get and set the data.

However, as [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) said, you'll need to be **authenticated-Logged-in** to be able to use Firebase database *update-remove* or etc. Otherwise, you should change your rules to open for everyone can do edits or etc.

Comment: Rules are open as of now, read and write are both true. Also the mRef for the child of `Data` is used to bind a recycler view. I won't be able to erase that and add this one.

Comment: You're actually making it difficult-complicated for yourself. For example, make an object of `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` then use it in your app by getting the `object.getDisplayName()` as an example. About the `RecyclerView` data, if you are unable to change that, you should create another query like in my answer to update the UID. Then, consider reading the documentation about the security rules and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code to update values in your database:

```java
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(),null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("Tag","SignInWithCredential: success");

                    FirebaseUser fUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    assert fUser != null;
                    User user = new User(fUser.getDisplayName(),fUser.getUid());
                    ref.child("users").child(fUser.getUid()).setValue(user);

                }
                else{
                    Log.w("TAG","SignInWithCredential: failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```